# Does anyone know when Canonical will release 16.04 AMIs for Amazon EC2?

Tags: server, 16.04, amazon-ec2

I'm searching [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) and I don't see it.

And I can't find any roadmap for when it might be released.

Is there usually a lag between release day and appearance of AMIs?

Comment: And now the AMIs have appeared! Still interested to hear if there might be some kind of a roadmap for AMIs getting published. Maybe the answer is just "sometime within a week or so after the launch" ?